# IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection when running app in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The code is very simple, just a Helloworld program, but when running it IDEA
gives me this error:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Build process started. Classpath: /E:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/lib/tools.jar;/E:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;E:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3/lib/ecj-4.4.jar
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:58568; reason: failed to create a child event loop
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:81)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:31)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:77)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:170)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
```

So what I can to do to fix this issue?

Comment: `at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:97)` try running intellij idea as "admin"

Comment: my system is windows 8.1 pro, JDK is 1.8

Comment: and this really is just `public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("Hello world!"); } }` right?

Comment: are you sure you are running just the `main` of your application and not some weird run configuration?

Comment: sorry i don't really understand this, is this is the code's question?

Comment: package com.exmple.hellowrold;

/**
 * Created by Young on 2015/6/3.
 */
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Helloworld");
    }
}

Comment: What is the run configuration?

Comment: is this means i need to edit configuration? sorry i'm new fresh

Comment: well, what tends to work for me is I just right click the class and say `run HelloWorld.main()` in the menu

Comment: the weird is i also click the run HelloWorld.main(), Ctrl + Shift + F10, it still can't work. oh my god i'm gonna to crazy

Comment: thanks a lot. i think i should install the system again.

Comment: You should probably reinstall intellij somewhere else. Some other folder. And run it as admin.  But if that doesn't work,  then I don't know.